# Search text in .txt files Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search

I want to search the content of text files using Windows 7.  I am unable to find stuff like `xyz` in `.txt` files that contain text like `asd**xyz**asd`, not even with the file search option enabled.

Comment: Maybe you'll like this: http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/106659/unicode-grep-for-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble trying to use Windows Search to search for file with a question mark in the content](http://superuser.com/questions/168638/trouble-trying-to-use-windows-search-to-search-for-file-with-a-question-mark-in)

Comment: Am I safe in assuming that you are indexing the contents .txt files? Are you able to find other strings inside the text file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [agent ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) which can see the contents inside the files and also search faster with the file name too. See the [feature](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=features) page.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has a feature for searching text in finds ('Find in files' tab under the regular ctrl+f search), and it's a pretty useful text editor in general.

Comment: Notepad++ is cool. I'm trying to decide if I like it better than Notepad2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "find" command in command interpreter (cmd.exe).
To gain more help, enter:

```
find /?
```

Usage:

```
find "text to find" files_to_find_in_-_can_be_wildcard
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for this task is to use a tool like [grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) - if you are looking only for text in text files, or [SeekFast](https://seekfast.org/) - if you want to search in any type of documents.