# Windows search is inaccurate with dots

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

When I search for files which have `127.0.0.1` in their content... It shows files that DO NOT have `127.0.0.1` in their content. What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you using Windows XP ? And in which type of files you want to search for that string?

Comment: Assuming from the last question (http://superuser.com/questions/432908/) he asked less than an hour ago, he is using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Within the search box type: `content: 127.0.0.1`.

Just tested it out on my Windows 7 system. It worked perfectly. I also tested just typing the IP address in. It worked too.

---

Since you are looking for `127.0.0.1` within a document(s) that contain `a127.0.0.1`, you could try searching for `~=127.0.0.1` per the solution of this [question](https://superuser.com/q/168638/20433).

Comment: I think you just tested it for search IPs like `127.0.0.1` but not `a127.0.0.1`. does it works for second IP types?

Comment: No. It's not going to work. It how Win7 search is now designed. It only works if you know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: As Windows 7 search uses regular expression, I think there must be a regular expression to do that.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/217491/20433) out. It will give my info how it works. In fact, this question might need to be closed all together since the two are very similar.

Comment: yeah, the answer in the question is right. It works with `~=127.0.0.1`. so , update your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. However, I was not able to produce the same results. If it works for you then so be it. That's all that really matters.